# CSV SQL: How to Achieve This?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

Using HXTT Text drivers to run queries on a CSV file. The CSV has entries like:

```
UID        Rights
User1      YYYY
User2      NNNN
User3      YNYN
User4      YYNN
```

Each character in Column B represent a role that the corresponding user has on the system. 'Y' means he has that role and 'N' means no. The roles are not referenced in the CSV and we have to hard code them. Lets assume the roles are:

1. First Character = Y means System Admin
2. Second Character = Y means Developer
3. Third Character = Y means DBA
4. Fourth Character = Y means User

The goal is to have a query which would give result in a separate rows if user has multiple roles. Taking the data from the table above, the result should look like:

```
UID     Rights   Role
User1   YYYY     System Admin
User1   YYYY     Developer
User1   YYYY     DBA
User1   YYYY     User
User2   NNNN     No Role
User3   YNYN     System Admin
User3   YNYN     DBA
```

and so on. Most of the Oracle SQL queries work using the Text driver and many don't. I would still like to understand how to achieve this.

Comment: How about just loading the data into a table in the database?

Comment: Not possible. The CSV must not be manipulated. If we create another file from the original, we will have to do that exercise every time there is a change in the original file.

Comment: So you have a job that triggers when the file changes.  I would question, though, why a system would be making changes to a file instead of making changes directly into an available database -- it sounds like a complex, bespoke architecture.

Comment: So we are collecting data from the CSV directly. The CSV comes from a system which processes all its data and spits it out in the form of this badly structured CSV.